# How do I create a multidimensional matrix (ArrayD) using ndarray?

Tags: multidimensional-array, rust

I would like to create a multidimensional matrix in Rust (the product of which exceeds 1e6). I found the `ndarray` crate, however the [documentation](https://docs.rs/ndarray/) gives no explanation on how to use the `ArrayD` type which seems to correspond to my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass a `&[usize]` (or `Vec<usize>`) containing N values with the shape of the array to create an N-dimensional array to any constructor function which accepts the shape of the array, like `Array::zeros`. For example, the following code creates an `Array` with 9 dimensions of shape `4 * 7 * 6 * 5 * 2 * 10 * 9 * 3 * 8`:

````
//! ```cargo
//! [dependencies]
//! ndarray = "*"
//! ```
extern crate ndarray;
use ndarray::ArrayD;

fn main() {
    let mut array = ArrayD::zeros([4, 7, 6, 5, 2, 10, 9, 3, 8].as_ref());
    array[[1; 9].as_ref()] = 123;

    println!("{:?}", array[[0; 9].as_ref()]);
    println!("{:?}", array[[1; 9].as_ref()]);
}
````

Output:

```
0
123
```